# Changing locale of user in home page of Grails application

Tags: grails, locale

I've been trying to change user locale after logging in (I use Spring Security).

I have tried changing the locale in the success event handler of Spring Security (onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) and also creating my own localeResolver and registering it on resources.groovy.

It seems to work fine for all the pages except for the home page.

This is MyLocaleResolver

```
class MyLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {

    def springSecurityService

    private Locale defaultLocale = null;

    @Override
    Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        User user = User.findByEmail(springSecurityService.authentication.principal.username)
        if (user && !defaultLocale) {
            if (user.lang) {
                this.defaultLocale = new Locale(user.lang)
            } else {
                this.defaultLocale = Locale.ENGLISH
            }
        }
        println "defaultLocale = $defaultLocale"
        return this.defaultLocale
    }

    @Override
    void setLocale(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Locale locale) {
        this.defaultLocale = locale;
    }
}
```

and the resources.groovy part

```
localeResolver(MyLocaleResolver){
    springSecurityService = ref("springSecurityService")
}
```

**Update (07/04/2015):**
I have already tried to extend CookieLocaleResolver, and because it sets the cookie value, it works fine in all cases except in the first home page load where the default language is set instead of the one that I set in the resolveLocale.

```
class MyLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver{

def springSecurityService

@Override
Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    super.resolveLocale(httpServletRequest)

    User user = User.findByEmail(springSecurityService.authentication.principal.username)
    Locale locale
    if (user) {
        if (user.lang) {
            locale = new Locale(user.lang)
        } else {
            locale = Locale.ENGLISH
        }
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute(LOCALE_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, locale != null?locale:this.determineDefaultLocale(request));
    }
    return (Locale)httpServletRequest.getAttribute(LOCALE_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
}
```

}

I have tried a differente approach, although I think it's better to try to override the localeResolver. I have tried to change the locale when the users login, changing the defaultLocale in the method loadUserByUsername of my MongoUserDetailsService. It happens the same than with the previous approach, it works well except on first home page load after loggin in.

```
def localeResolver

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User.withTransaction { status ->
               User user = User.findByEmail(username)
               if (!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                            'User not found', username)

                try {
                    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(user.lang ? new Locale(user.lang) : Locale.ENGLISH)
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

               def authorities = user.authorities.collect {
                   new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.authority)
               }

               return new MyUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
                  !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                  !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: MongoUserDetailsService.NO_ROLES, user.id, user.client, user.email,
                    user.dateCreated)
            }
}
```

and the resources.groovy

```
userDetailsService(net.ds.batto.MongoUserDetailsService){
    localeResolver = ref("localeResolver")
}
```

Also, I thought that grails used CookieLocaleResolver by default, but I have seen that the localeResolver that I get reference of is of SessionLocaleResolver. Is this the right behaviour or may there be something misconfigured?

Comment: Unsure if it's a better approach but it might worth investigation: Have you considered overriding org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor ? I imagine altering the preHandle method may offer additional control over Homepage first load behaviour. Making it aware of logged user earlier. http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Changing-request-Locale-for-i18n-in-grails-application-using-Interceptor

Comment: Also I'm surprised to see Locale modification in the loadByUserName method of the UserDetailsService. Changing session Locale has nothing to do with retrieving/loading user from DB. Any reason you didn't maintained it in the authenticationSuccessEventListener(com.example.Authenticatio‌​nSuccessEventListene‌​r) as initially described in your message??

Answer (score 0):

To me defaultLocale is global configuration for the whole application (or at least not for a particular user session)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html

> Custom controllers can override the user's locale and time zone by calling #setLocale(Context) on the resolver

So maybe you can try to replace

```
localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(user.lang ? new Locale(user.lang) : Locale.ENGLISH)
```

by

```
class MyLocaleChangeInterceptor extends LocaleChangeInterceptor {
        ...
    @Override
    boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        localeResolver.setLocale(user.lang ? new Locale(user.lang):Locale.ENGLISH)
    }
}
```

directly in the LocaleChangeInterceptor, I guess it's already too late when server reaches 'LocaleResolver' Request has already been processed, only following request will be affected by the Locale change.